# Disabling Enter Key while MsgBox is Open in VB

Tags: vb.net

When users are working they press the Enter Key very fast because that way they go through the form to the Accept Button at the end of the form. There is a MsgBox with Yes And Now , that opens as a last step before  the form closes. That way with fast pressing multiple times the Enter Key the user accidentally presses Yes, coz the default button is Yes. Setting the default Key to No is not option.
So is there any way to dont allow pressing enter in the msgbox?

Comment: One workaround could be to design a form that looks like a message prompt and then have a timer on there to wait 5 seconds before enabling the buttons?

Comment: The documentation on how to detect the enter key might help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx.
Maybe you can override it?

Comment: Thanks but i am on .net 1.1 framework :(

Comment: You can also disable the focus on those yes/no buttons.